# C# Core MVC - <script> populate a textarea after dropdown list onchange event

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net-core

I'm trying to fill a text area on my MVC view after retrieving a subset of data. I can get the data, but need to update the view with the returned data

Here is the code I have tried:

```
<div class="box-shadow">
    <p>Please select an Area Path and Iteration Path below:</p>
    <table>
        <tr>
            <th>Area Path</th>
            <th>Iteration Path</th>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td>
                @Html.DropDownList("MySpecialAreaPathsList",((List<string>)ViewBag.myAreaPathsList).Select(m => new SelectListItem { Text = m, Value = m }),
                null, new { @onchange =  "GetAreaPathValue()" })
            </td>
```

```
        <tr>
            <td>
                <textarea class="text-info" id="txtLog" style="width:1080px;height:200px"></textarea>
            </td>
```

---

```
function GetAreaPathValue() {
        var selectedElement = document.querySelector('#MySpecialAreaPathsList');
        var option = selectedElement.value;
        $.ajax({
            url: '@Url.Action("GetAreaPathChildren", "MyController")',
            type: "GET",
            data: { 'areapathText': option },
            success: function (data) { $('#txtLog').value(data) }
        })
    }
```

Can someone help me with getting the return data from GetAreaPathChildren (the return value is a List but I'd be happy just getting a string (or any value actually)

Comment: What you are getting in `data`? What does your List containing? Within the list which want you would like to bind in  `#txtLog`?

Comment: overall -- this is pulling all Area Paths from Azure DevOps. When I click on the DropDownList and select one of the area paths, I have a method that pulls all the children of the area paths. So, Ideally I'd like to retrieve a List<string>. However, right now, even if I got a string to test I would be happy. I've tried both ways, and since it is a textarea I set the method output to string output+= childPath; (Note: I set success: alert(data) and can see in the popup on the screen)

Comment: It would be great if you could include sample data list along with its type what you are getting and would like to bind in your textarea. Desire result or output.

Comment: Not sure how best to explain. Essentially the method pulls all children under and Area Path list from Azure DevOps. So If the user selects "Parent\Department" from the dropdown list, the child paths would be returned such as: Parent\Department\WorkStream One
Parent\Department\WorkStream Two
Parent\Department\WorkStream Three ...... so the data returned to the Text area would be Parent\Department\WorkStream One
Parent\Department\WorkStream Two
Parent\Department\WorkStream Three

Comment: Thanks for your response, please try the solution, it would resolve your issue. here you have done the mistake `$('#txtLog').val(data)`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> I'm trying to fill a text area on my MVC view after retrieving a
> subset of data. I can get the data, but need to update the view with
> the returned data

Well, based on your shared code snippet, I have successfully reproduced your scenario. The reason why your data is not appending to your `textarea` as expected has pretty obvious reason. If you check your browser `console.log` you would get below error:

[image]

**Reason Of Error:**

You are using wrong javascript attribute `value`. Its incorrect. It should be `val`  insteaed of `value`. Therefore, your code snippet would be
`$('#txtLog').val(data.message)` instead of
`$('#txtLog').value(data)`

**Complete Solution**

Controller:

```
public class AppendTextAreaController : Controller
    {
        public IActionResult Index()
        {
            
            List<string> MySpecialAreaPathsList = new List<string>();
            MySpecialAreaPathsList.Add("C#");
            MySpecialAreaPathsList.Add("SQL");
            MySpecialAreaPathsList.Add("Asp.net core");
            ViewBag.myAreaPathsList = MySpecialAreaPathsList;
            return View();
        }
        [HttpGet]
        public JsonResult GetAreaPathChildren(string areapathText)
        {
           
            return new JsonResult(new { message = string.Format("Data From Controller and parameter passed: {0}",areapathText)  });

        }
    }
```

View:

```
<div class="box-shadow">
    <p>Please select an Area Path and Iteration Path below:</p>
    <table>
        <tr>
            <th>Area Path</th>
            <th>Iteration Path</th>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td>
                @Html.DropDownList("MySpecialAreaPathsList",((List<string>)ViewBag.myAreaPathsList).Select(m => new SelectListItem { Text = m, Value = m }),
                null, new { @onchange =  "GetAreaPathValue()" })
            </td>
        <tr>
            <td>
                <textarea class="text-info" id="txtLog" style="width:1080px;height:200px"></textarea>
            </td>
    </table>
</div>
@section Scripts {
   
    <script>
        function GetAreaPathValue() {
            alert("Inside Func");
            var selectedElement = document.querySelector('#MySpecialAreaPathsList');
            var option = selectedElement.value;
            $.ajax({
                url: '@Url.Action("GetAreaPathChildren", "AppendTextArea")',
                type: "GET",
                data: { 'areapathText': option },
                success: function (data) {
                    console.log(data);
                    $('#txtLog').val(data.message)

                }
            })
        }
    </script>
}
```

Output:

[image]

**Note:**

Remember that, if you return your data from controller like this

```
                var message = string.Format("Data From Controller and parameter passed: {0}", areapathText);
                return new JsonResult(message);
```

In that scenario, you should get this data in your view as below:

`$('#txtLog').val(data)`

You could refer below code snippet as well.

```
        [HttpGet]
        public JsonResult GetAreaPathChildren(string areapathText)
        {
            var message = string.Format("Data From Controller and parameter passed: {0}", areapathText);
            return new JsonResult(message);

        }
```

Comment: Glad to assist you.